# LNK2019: Calling C function from CPP code

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, mfc, visual-studio-2015

I have created an MSVS2015 project (MFC/C++) which 
links with a static C library. When I build the
projects I get the following error:

```
error LNK2019: 
unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl testLinkerError(void)" (?testLinkerError@@YAXXZ) referenced 
in function "void __cdecl test1(void)" (?test1@@YAXXZ)  [PATH_REMOVED]\test.obj [NAME_OF_MFC_PROJECT]
```

For debugging purposes, I have created 3 files:

```
test.cpp
linkertest.c
linkertest.h
```

1. test.cpp has been added to the MFC project and it looks like this:

> ```
> #include "linkertest.h"
>
> void test1(void)
> {
>    testLinkerError();
> }
> ```

2. The header file linkertest.h looks like this:

> ```
> #pragma once
>
> #ifdef _cplusplus
> extern "C" {
> #endif
>
> void testLinkerError(void);
>
> #ifdef _cplusplus
> }
> #endif
> ```

3. And linkertest.c looks like this:

> ```
> #include "linkertest.h"
>
> void testLinkerError(void) {    
>      int x = 5;    
>      int y = 7;    
>      int z = x + y; 
>   }
> ```

I am quite sure that this is some kind of name mangling issue, but I can't figure out how to solve it.
The calling convention in both projects is set to __cdecl

Comment: Are you sure your compiler provides `_cplusplus`?  I have only ever seen it with _two_ leading underscores, and as far as I know that's the closest you can get to any "standard".  Are you certain that you have included the **.lib** file in the Additional Libraries section of your project settings _and_ that it's set for the build configuration you're compiling against?

Comment: Just saw @paddy's comment, which I believe is the correct answer. FWIW the linker error indicates that the C++ compile ignores the `extern "C"` part, see [Name Decoration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deaxefa7.aspx) for details.

Comment: I need a gun so I can shoot myself in the head. Let me try and fix that typo.

Comment: It's a common misconception that this requires a gun, when in fact the same end result can be achieved with a crossbow or a falling piano... ;)  But seriously, please don't harm yourself.  That is not an effective way to learn from mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on the compiler error, you compiler tried to look up `?testLinkerError@@YAXXZ` which is a C++ function name. so which means on your import part (not your DLL export) you did not use `extern "C"`....

and one more thing, The name `__cplusplus` (two underscores) is defined to the value 201402L when compiling a C++ translation unit. please check your code make sure `_cplusplus` (one underscore) is defined.

Comment: The problem was indeed the missing underscore! I spent 2 hours on this and it turns out to be a type. I feel like shooting myself in the head right now. Thanks a lot guys! :-)